# Search mysql data of the given month

Tags: php, mysql, date

Here is my selection code

```
<select id="month_id" name="month_id">

  <option value="">Select One</option>

  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-01-01 00:00:00'); ?>">January</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-02-01 00:00:00'); ?>">February</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-03-01 00:00:00'); ?>">March</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-04-01 00:00:00'); ?>">April</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-05-01 00:00:00'); ?>">May</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-06-01 00:00:00'); ?>">June</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-07-01 00:00:00'); ?>">July</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-08-01 00:00:00'); ?>">August</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-09-01 00:00:00'); ?>">September</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-10-01 00:00:00'); ?>">October</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-11-01 00:00:00'); ?>">November</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-12-01 00:00:00'); ?>">December</option>
</select>
```

Data stored in db table by date in a format where date column likes 
**2013-01-14 17:40:12**

Now suppose I select January and then Click submit. I want to fetch those data in which date column values are between January 1 to 31 of that Year.

Comment: Please don't mind me asking, but where are you stuck?

Comment: What will be sql query ?

Comment: In order to provide a query, you should provide the table description together with some code to show what effort you have already put into the solution of your issue at hand.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MONTH(date_column)=MONTH('2013-03-31 13:13:10')
```

just extract the month value from the posted date like

```
$whole_date=$_POST['month_id'];
$query=" SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MONTH(date_column)=MONTH('".$whole_date."')";
```

OR

```
$month=date("m", strtotime($whole_date));
$query=" SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MONTH(date_column)=$month";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'value=' statement to just send the year and month(or parse them out before you generate the query)

Then your query will look (something) like:

```
select * from <sometable> where YEAR(datecolumn)=<year value> 
       and MONTH(datecolumn)=<month value>
```